# Mongoose update multiple fields in one document in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've a collection of ranks in ship. It has **rank** and **type**.

Some of the ranks and their corresponding types are:

1. BOSUN -> Crew
2. OS -> Crew
3. FITTER -> Crew

and some other officer types. User can edit both rank and types(If there's typo or the rank is in wrong type). But I just find the correct mongoose way to do so. This is what I've tried

```
const editOneRank = async (req, res) => {
    const rank = req.body.rank;
    const rankData = await Rank.findOne({rank});
    console.log(rankData);
    if(!rankData){
        res.status(200).send({
            message: "rank not found",
        })
    }else{
        const editedRankFromBody = new Rank({
            rank: req.body.rank,
            type: req.body.type
        });
        
        try{
            await Rank.findOneAndUpdate(rankData._id, {"rank": req.body.rank,"type": req.body.type}, (err, result)=>{
                if(err){
                    res.status(400).send({
                        data: "couldn't update rank"
                    })
                }else{
                    console.log(result);
                    res.status(200).send({
                        data: "Rank Updated"
                    })
                }
            })
        }catch(err){
            res.status(400).send({
                data: err+ "hello"
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't update anything I also tried:

```
await Rank.findOneAndUpdate(rankData._id, {"type": req.body.type}, (err, result)=>{})
```

with no luck. What am I doing wrong? How do I update both rank and type if somehow the user needs to update both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try to update using the following:

```
await Rank.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":rankData._id},
 {
   "$set":{
     "rank": req.body.rank,"type": req.body.type
   }
 },
 (err, result)=>{})
```

I think you've missed the field name to check for and update its data.

Comment: It worked. I thought editing was similar to adding.

Comment: Okay, Glad to help you.